# Availability Calendar Ideas

Tags: calendar

I have an interesting situation here this time.

This more of a conceptual question, less of a technical code question.

I need to have an 'availability calendar' for a new web application.
The calendar needs to allow users to easily choose dates that are unavailable at the cottage (and update them in the future).

Any ideas for a calendar or a simple and effective method to do this would be great.
I've seen various jQuery and similar calendars, however none of them seem to make it easy to select dates in various months, etc.

Thanks in advance,

Craig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to make a calendar easy to use for the selection of date ranges is to imitate certain aspects of how a roulette board is used to select ranges of numbers. For example, clicking on a region either side of a week would select the whole week, while clicking on a region above/below a particular day of the week would select all days of the week for that month.

Comment: This sounds very interesting.. have you ever seen it in play before? Example?

Comment: Sorry, the only working instances of this I've seen were proprietary code in private systems.

Comment: That's alright. I'm going to see what I can find, but it sounds like an interesting concept. You would think this would have been made at some point, somewhere along the line..

Answer (score 0):

Roulette - this came to my mind

http://www.marca.com/deporte/futbol/mundial/sudafrica-2010/calendario-english.html

Comment: I like the concept of this, but in practice I am looking for something that is easy to select dates in for the admin user.
Displaying availability dates will be the easier of the two parts. I need a module to allow selection of many dates at one time. (as well as a logical method of storing this data in a database)